# call jquery function on aspmenu item click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have aspmenu item onmy project and on the submenu of menu item click i want to pop up one div dialog box.
my aspmenuitem is here

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
   <Items>
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Parties.aspx" Text="Parties" />
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Accounts.aspx" Text="Accounts" />
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Funds.aspx" Text="Funds" />
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/FundTransfer.aspx" Text="Fund Transfer" />
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Receipts.aspx" Text="Receipts" />
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Payments.aspx" Text="Payments" />
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/AccountCategory.aspx" Text="Account Category" />
      <asp:MenuItem Text="Reports">
         <asp:MenuItem CssClass="sd" Text="Bank Reconcilation" />
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Anexure" />
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Statements" />
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Categorywise Statements" />
      </asp:MenuItem>
   </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

here i have used cssclass for that but it gives me runtime error: "MenuItem does not have a public property named 'CssClass'"

kindly help me to solve this issue
Thank in advance

Comment: so what is your issue CssClass or Popup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your menu as mentioned below :

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <LevelSubMenuStyles>
        <asp:submenustyle /> 
        <asp:submenustyle CssClass="sd"/> 
    </LevelSubMenuStyles>
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Parties.aspx" Text="Parties" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Accounts.aspx" Text="Accounts" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Funds.aspx" Text="Funds" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/FundTransfer.aspx" Text="Fund Transfer" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Receipts.aspx" Text="Receipts" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/Payments.aspx" Text="Payments" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Cashbook/AccountCategory.aspx" Text="Account Category" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Reports">
            <asp:MenuItem  Text="Bank Reconcilation" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Anexure" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Statements" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Categorywise Statements" />
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Then Add `DIV` tag for dialog :

```
<div id="dialog" title="Contact form">
    <p>Hi, I am dialog</p>
</div>
```

Then add script to initialize and display dialog box by clicking on submenu

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // this initializes the dialog (and uses some common options that I do)
    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, show: "blind", hide: "blind" });


    $('.sd').click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .
it helps me a lot.
now dialog gets open but another issue is that when i click on 
submenu dialog will open for a moment an page gets refreshed so it will deshappear.

how can i prevent my page to get refreshed ??

Comment: Add **NavigateUrl="#"** for the sub menu item. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer. so that it may help other users as well.